# Comparing whether JSON paths are equivalent other than indexes

Tags: python, json

Following the syntax from [jsonpath_ng](https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng):

```py
path = '$.data.objects[*].currencies[*].name'
related = '$.data.objects[4].currencies[0].name'
unrelated = '$.data.objects[4].currencies[0].value'
```

I am looking to compare whether two strings representing JSON paths in Python are equivalent if we ignore any indexes. For example, `related` would be compliant with `path` whereas `unrelated` wouldn't.

Is there a cleaner way to do this other than regex? I am already using `jsonpath_ng` in this module but cannot see support for this functionality.

To be clear: this operation is independent of any subsequent JSON object referencing, I just want to determine whether the paths themselves are similar.

Comment: you need to give more information, a small example from your json so others can understand better.

Comment: Sorry, have clarified the question to indicate the check should be on the path string itself, and not related to any specific JSON. In other words, I am not interested in the value at those paths, just whether `related` complies with `path`.

Comment: `json_ng.parse()` returns an AST, so you could visit the ASTs for each expression and for each node decide if it "matches" the other's.  Reading the package's source code might help...